# Can't retrieve data from JavaScript local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I was wondering if you could take a look at my code. I can't work out why I'm not able to retrieve the data in local storage. The data is taken from a form into local storage then retrieved on the form submission page but it doesn't seem to be transferring correctly as when I try to use the data or print it, nothing happens or it doesn't show. Thankyou

gameFunctions.js

```
//This is the Javascript code file for Spelling Game

//variable to store which age group the user has selected
var ageGroup;

//function that changes the audio files 
function ageSelected(age) {

  if (age == '6-9') {
    //changes the 'select a difficulty' text to confirm the user's difficulty selection
    document.getElementById("difficulty").innerHTML = "You have selected: <b>Ages 6-9</b>"

    //the remaining code changes the audio sources to the chosen difficulty
    document.getElementById("firstAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/stop.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerOne").load();

    document.getElementById("secondAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/breakfast.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerTwo").load();

    document.getElementById("thirdAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/together.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerThree").load();

    document.getElementById("fourthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/saturday.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFour").load();

    document.getElementById("fifthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/goat.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFive").load();

    ageGroup = "6-9";
  } else if (age == '10-13') {
    //changes the 'select a difficulty' text to confirm the user's difficulty selection
    document.getElementById("difficulty").innerHTML = "You have selected: <b>Ages 10-13</b>"

    //the remaining code changes the audio sources to the chosen difficulty
    document.getElementById("firstAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/government.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerOne").load();

    document.getElementById("secondAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/weird.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerTwo").load();

    document.getElementById("thirdAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/mortgage.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerThree").load();

    document.getElementById("fourthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/recycle.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFour").load();

    document.getElementById("fifthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/questionnaire.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFive").load();

    ageGroup = "10-13";
  } else if (age == '14-17') {
    //changes the 'select a difficulty' text to confirm the user's difficulty selection
    document.getElementById("difficulty").innerHTML = "You have selected: <b>Ages 14-17</b>"

    //the remaining code changes the audio sources to the chosen difficulty
    document.getElementById("firstAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/elimination.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerOne").load();

    document.getElementById("secondAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/technique.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerTwo").load();

    document.getElementById("thirdAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/retaliate.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerThree").load();

    document.getElementById("fourthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/ambiguous.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFour").load();

    document.getElementById("fifthAudio").setAttribute("src", "sounds/camouflage.mp3");
    document.getElementById("audioContainerFive").load();

    ageGroup = "14-17";
  }

  //stores ageGroup in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("ageGroup", ageGroup);

  //removes the age select buttons after the player has chosen a difficulty
  document.getElementById("age69").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("age1013").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("age1417").style.display = "none";

  //displays the restart button to refresh the page
  document.getElementById("btnReset").style.display = "block";
}

//counts number of fields left blank
var count = 0;

//function to check that all questions have been answered
function validate(event) {
  //get all guesses
  var textBox = document.getElementsByClassName("textBox");

  //count the empty textboxes
  var i = textBox.length;

  for (i; i > count; i--) {
    if (textBox[i - 1].value == "") {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  }

  //output message if not all guesses are complete
  if (count != 0) {
    window.alert("You must answer all the questions!");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

//function called when clicking the submit button on the form
function submitAnswers() {
  //get the value inside of each textbox
  var answerOne = document.getElementById("firstGuess").value;
  var answerTwo = document.getElementById("secondGuess").value;
  var answerThree = document.getElementById("thirdGuess").value;
  var answerFour = document.getElementById("fourthGuess").value;
  var answerFive = document.getElementById("fifthGuess").value;

  //convert user inputted data to lower case so it matches the correct answer variables' case
  var lowAnswerOne = toLowerCase(answerOne);
  var lowAnswerTwo = toLowerCase(answerTwo);
  var lowAnswerThree = toLowerCase(answerThree);
  var lowAanswerFour = toLowerCase(answerFour);
  var lowAanswerFive = toLowerCase(answerFive);

  //put each value into localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("answerOne", lowAnswerOne);
  localStorage.setItem("answerTwo", lowAnswerTwo);
  localStorage.setItem("answerThree", lowAnswerThree);
  localStorage.setItem("answerFour", lowAanswerFour);
  localStorage.setItem("answerFive", lowAanswerFive);

  return true;
}

//function containing an if statement thatc ontrols which textbox to enter
//text into depending on whether the textbox is active or not
function typeLetter(letter) {

  if (document.getElementById("second").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("secondGuess").value += letter;
  } else if (document.getElementById("third").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("thirdGuess").value += letter;
  } else if (document.getElementById("fourth").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("fourthGuess").value += letter;
  } else if (document.getElementById("fifth").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("fifthGuess").value += letter;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("firstGuess").value += letter;
  }
}

//functions to control when each question is displayed after clicking a next 
or previous button

function nextQuestionOne() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q2").innerHTML = "&#9899";
}

function previousQuestionOne() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("q2").innerHTML = "&#9898";
}

function nextQuestionTwo() {
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q3").innerHTML = "&#9899";
}

function previousQuestionTwo() {
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q3").innerHTML = "&#9898";
}

function nextQuestionThree() {
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q4").innerHTML = "&#9899";
}

function previousQuestionThree() {
  document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q4").innerHTML = "&#9898";
}

function nextQuestionFour() {
  document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q5").innerHTML = "&#9899";
}

function previousQuestionFour() {
  document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q5").innerHTML = "&#9898";
}

//function to refresh the page when the 'Restart Game' button is clicked
function refreshPage() {
  var confirmRefresh = confirm("Do you really want to restart the game?");

  if (confirmRefresh) {
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

resultsCode.js

```
//This is the code for the Results page

//function verifies the player's answers, calculates score and gives option 
to add to leaderboard

function run() {

  //define correct answer variables
  var correctAnswerOne, correctAnswerTwo, correctAnswerThree,
    correctAnswerFour, correctAnswerFive;

  //define variable to keep player's score
  var playerScore = 0;

  //get ageGroup from localStorage
  var ageGroup = localStorage.getItem("ageGroup");

  //get answers from localStorage and store in variables
  var answerOne = localStorage.getItem("answerOne");
  var answerTwo = localStorage.getItem("answerTwo");
  var answerThree = localStorage.getItem("answerThree");
  var answerFour = localStorage.getItem("answerFour");
  var answerFive = localStorage.getItem("answerFive");


  //populate the table with player's answers
  document.getElementById("aOne").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answerOne");
  document.getElementById("aTwo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answerTwo");
  document.getElementById("aThree").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answerThree");
  document.getElementById("aFour").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answerFour");
  document.getElementById("aFive").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answerFive");

  //depending on which ageGroup was selected, the correct answers are different
  if (ageGroup == "6-9") {
    //assign answers to variables
    correctAnswerOne = "stop";
    correctAnswerTwo = "breakfast";
    correctAnswerThree = "together";
    correctAnswerFour = "saturday";
    correctAnswerFive = "goat";

    document.getElementById("qOne").innerHTML = correctAnswerOne;
    document.getElementById("qTwo").innerHTML = correctAnswerTwo;
    document.getElementById("qThree").innerHTML = correctAnswerThree;
    document.getElementById("qFour").innerHTML = correctAnswerFour;
    document.getElementById("qFive").innerHTML = correctAnswerFive;

  } else if (ageGroup == "10-13") {
    //assign answers to variables
    correctAnswerOne = "government";
    correctAnswerTwo = "weird";
    correctAnswerThree = "mortgage";
    correctAnswerFour = "recycle";
    correctAnswerFive = "questionnaire";

    document.getElementById("qOne").innerHTML = correctAnswerOne;
    document.getElementById("qTwo").innerHTML = correctAnswerTwo;
    document.getElementById("qThree").innerHTML = correctAnswerThree;
    document.getElementById("qFour").innerHTML = correctAnswerFour;
    document.getElementById("qFive").innerHTML = correctAnswerFive;
  } else if (ageGroup == "14-17") {
    //assign answers to variables
    correctAnswerOne = "elimination";
    correctAnswerTwo = "technique";
    correctAnswerThree = "retaliate";
    correctAnswerFour = "ambiguous";
    correctAnswerFive = "camouflage";

    document.getElementById("qOne").innerHTML = correctAnswerOne;
    document.getElementById("qTwo").innerHTML = correctAnswerTwo;
    document.getElementById("qThree").innerHTML = correctAnswerThree;
    document.getElementById("qFour").innerHTML = correctAnswerFour;
    document.getElementById("qFive").innerHTML = correctAnswerFive;
  }

  if (answerOne == correctAnswerOne) {
    playerScore++;
    document.getElementById("cOne").innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cOne").innerHTML = "No";
  }

  if (answerTwo == correctAnswerTwo) {
    playerScore++;
    document.getElementById("cTwo").innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cTwo").innerHTML = "No";
  }

  if (answerThree == correctAnswerThree) {
    playerScore++;
    document.getElementById("cThree").innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cThree").innerHTML = "No";
  }

  if (answerFour == correctAnswerFour) {
    playerScore++;
    document.getElementById("cFour").innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cFour").innerHTML = "No";
  }

  if (answerFive == correctAnswerFive) {
    playerScore++;
    document.getElementById("cFive").innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cFive").innerHTML = "No";
  }

  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your final score is: " + "<b>" + playerScore + "</b>";
```

Comment: You know that you must be running your page(s) from a server for `localStorage` to work, right?

Comment: @ScottMarcus no, I thought that localStorage was client-side?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997292/localstorage-access-from-local-file

Comment: It is client side, but there are security restrictions that can only be implemented when responses to the client come from a server. localStorage will not work when working straight from the file system.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is there any way to work around this just using HTML/JavaScript without a server to be able to display form responses?

Comment: No. But, there are plenty of free servers you can installl. Visual studio community edition is a great IDE with an integrated server.