# How to store image locally from image URL by using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tizen, tizen-web-app

I want to store image locally and use it to anywhere in tizen application.

I tried by using canvas but canvas data uri not showing exact image which have in URL.

The snippet of code who I am using.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = imageURL;

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var data = context.getImageData(x, y, img.width, img.height).data;

localStorage.setItem('image', data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you want save an `array` to `localStorage`. Instead of `context.getImageData()` you have to use `canvas.toDataURL()` and then convert `dataURL` to Base64 string image. After this you can save it to the `localStorage`.

Your image must be online and in the same domain like your script. It is because of [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). But if you convert your image like me in `dataURL` before and then you should not have any problem.

And to `localStorage` you have today (in 2018) an access only in online mode. Please read:

- [localStorage access from local file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24997292)

**Full example**

See this working example on **[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXqGzy)** (link to example) because on StackOverflow the snippets are sandboxed and because of this we can not have an access to the `localStorage`.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var image = new Image();
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

image.onload = function()
{
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    var Base64StringImage = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

    localStorage.setItem('image', Base64StringImage);

    //read from localStorage:
    document.querySelector('img').src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + localStorage.getItem('image');
};

image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
```

```html
<img src="#">
```

Comment: I have used this canvas.toDataURL("image/png") but it is not displaying exact image who has in URL.

Comment: I am asking about stored image in local storage from image URL but your example not with image URL.

Comment: @ManjeetKumar, I wrotte you already in my answer: **your image must be online and in the same domain like your script**. But you did not tried it! Why? If you want an image URL. then instead of `image.src = 'data:image/png...` write `image.src = yourImageURL`. But it must be on your server. Read my answer again please.

Comment: @ManjeetKumar, or you could convert all your images into dataURL images like in my example. Use **[this online convert service](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php)** for this.

Comment: Image is store in other server. I have image URL and I am trying to store image in local. Is it possible to store other sever image in local ?

Comment: @ManjeetKumar, yes it is possible to store other sever image in local, but you have to convert all your images into dataURL images like in my example. Use **[this online convert service](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php)** for this. How many images do you have? (**this is question**) Or you could give all the links and I convert your images  into dataURL images.