# Strange behaviour of onAuthStateChanged() when persistence is set to local

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web app with two pages - index.html(using the script loginPage.js) and polls.html(using the script polls.js). The index.html just has a login form while polls.html has a signout button. Clicking the signout button calls signOut() and clicking login button calls login(). Here are the two scripts with the functions-
loginPage.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user){
        window.location="polls.html";
    }
});

function login() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function () {
                console.log("Logged in");
                if (document.getElementById("ckbxRememberMe").checked) {
                    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error.message);
                            console.log(error.code);
                        });
                } else {
                    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error.message);
                            console.log(error.code);
                        });
                }
        });
}
```

polls.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    userGLobal = user;
    if (user) {
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
            displayMessage("You need to verify your email before you can cast your votes.");
        }
        loadActivePolls();
    } else {
        window.location = "index.html";
    }
});

function signOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
        .catch(function(error) {
            displayMessage("Couldn't sign you out.");
            console.log(error.code);
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}
```

Everything works well if I don't check the "remember me" checkbox and set the persistence to "session" but checking the checkbox(thus setting the persistence to "local") induces a very strange behaviour. It causes the web app to oscillate between index.html and poll.html. I don't understand why this is happening.

EDIT: This doesn't happen when the website is hosted. The problem occurs only when the web-app is being running locally by opening index.html in a browser.

Comment: _"opening index.html in a browser"_. You really should have mentioned that earlier. Does this answer your question? [localStorage access from local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997292/localstorage-access-from-local-file). Bottom line, use `firebase serve` when developing locally

Comment: Thanks. You should make this an answer since someone else might stumble upon this/similar problem as working in firebase means that the person might not have a server and may be doing things locally like I was.